# Pyspark can't find csv in docker

Tags: docker, csv, pyspark

I'm new to Docker and pyspark...

I have a docker image which runs on python3.7-alpine. For now i just want to read a csv file into a spark dataframe

```
    spark = SparkSession. \
                    builder. \
                    appName("pythonfile"). \
                    master("spark://spark-master:7077"). \
                    config("spark.executor.memory", "512m"). \
                    getOrCreate()

    spark.read.option('header', True).csv('Crimes_2001_to_Present.csv')
```

but i get a:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/Crimes_2001_to_Present.csv does not exist
```

before i try to read in the csv i printed out my current working directory and all folders and files within that working directory

```
print(os.getcwd())
print(os.listdir())
```

and my bash is printing out that the csv file is in that directory:

```
pythonfile_1      | /
pythonfile_1      | ['home', 'srv', 'etc', 'opt', 'root', 'lib', 'mnt', 'usr', 'media', 'sys', 'dev', 
'sbin', 'bin', 'run', 'proc', 'tmp', 'var', 'data', '__pycache__', '.dockerenv', 
'Crimes_2001_to_Present.csv', 'Get_data.py', 'Main.py', 'Transform_data.py']
```

does anyone know - or give me a hint - why pyspark can't find this csv ?

```
pyspark version = 3.0.1
spark_version = 3.0.1
hadoop_version = 2.7
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: How are you launching the application? Are you using standalone or yarn? Depending on the configuration you'll have to place the file where the executors can reach (e.g. hdfs), not only where the driver is. Or just try `master("local[*]")` since you're testing.

Comment: Im launching the application in the Dockerfile related to the docker image i build.. CMD ['python', './Get_Data.py']
 I tried master('local[*]') but it still can't find the file... I even tried with SparkContext

Comment: That should have worked, we're still missing information then. Can you add a minimal dockerfile example that reproduces the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Solution:

I had to use an Ubuntu Image as a docker Image.
I installed on this docker image python pyspark and spark.
Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest


RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install git -y
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install wget -y

COPY handler.py /
COPY Crimes.csv /

RUN wget 'https://downloads.apache.org/spark/spark-3.0.1/spark-3.0.1-bin- 
hadoop2.7.tgz'
RUN tar -xzvf spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz
RUN rm spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz

RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip python3-dev python3
RUN apt-get update

RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip

RUN ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python

RUN pip install pyspark


RUN sed -i.py 's/\r$//' handler.py
CMD ./spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit --master spark://spark-master:7077 -- 
files Crimes.csv ./handler.py
```

The spark-submit command with --files is uploading the csv to the master and all slaves.
After this i was able to read in the CSV file with following code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkFiles

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("pysparkapp").config("spark.executor.memory", 
"512m").getOrCreate()

sc = spark.sparkContext

df = sc.textFile(SparkFiles.get('Crimes.csv'))
```

The SparkFiles.get('fileName') gets the path from the file within the spark system, which was uploaded with the spark-submit --files command.